# How to make sequential api calls in ionic2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I am completely new to ionic2 and javascript coding. My problem is like this.

I have a js file in whose constructor I make a web api call and saves the response in a variable var1. I have another method which makes a second api call to another endpoint using var1. This  second method is an exported function and is being called from another file. Now as soon as the second  method is called, the constructor is loaded which makes the first api call and before the response could be stored in var1 the second api call is made from the exported method, using var1 as blank.  How can I avoid this. I want to wait untill var1 has been updated via the constructor.

This is my constructor code:

```
constructor(public http: Http, platform: Platform) {
   //console.log(this.http.get("http://freegeoip.net/json/"));
   this.http.get("http://freegeoip.net/json/").map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        if(data.country_code=="US")
          this.country_code = 1;
        else  if(data.country_code=="IN")
          this.country_code = 2;
    });
  }
```

This is the exported method being called:

```
load(): Observable<Post[]> {
...
let opt: RequestOptions;
  opt = new RequestOptions({
   headers: headers
  });
    return this.http.get(`${this.backand_api_url}`+this.country_code+'/posts', opt )
      .map(res => <Post[]>res.json().data);
  }

}
```

The load method is uses this.country_code variable.. which is still not updated from the constructor call.

EDIT the load() method returns an observable.

Comment: Have you tried to return a Promise in your HTTP call and execute the load method on resolve success?

Comment: I am not sure if that would help my case,  the load function is called on a user action. If I use promise that way, everytime the constructor would be called the load method will also be called automatically.

Comment: Don't save the variable in `var1`, instead return a promise for `var1` and chain from that promise.

Comment: Can you explain in detail a code example maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Use publishLast().refCont() in constructor and withLatestFrom in load. Something like that:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'haha',
  template: 'number is {{y}}'
})
export class HahaComponent {
  init$: Observable<number>;
  y: number;

  constructor() {
    this.init$ = Observable.of(1)
      .delay(10000)
      .do(x => {
        console.log('init', x);
        this.y = x;
      })
      .publishLast()
      .refCount();
  }

  load() {
    console.log('load');
    this.init$
      .withLatestFrom(Observable.of(2), (a, b) => b)
      .do(x => console.log(x))
      .subscribe(x => this.y = this.y + x);
  }
}
```